# copy sheet to another workbook but the sheet is also saved in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I need to copy a sheet from one workbook to another (existing) workbook. It works but the sheet is also automatically saved in a new workbook. I have no idea why this is. this is my code:

```
Worksheets("New").Activate
If IsSheetEmpty(StartWorkbook.Sheets("New")) = True Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets("New").Delete
    OLDWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("sheet1").Select
    Sheets("sheet1").Copy
    Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=StartWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
    StartWorkbook.Activate
    Sheets("sheet1").Name = "New"
    OLD.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True   
Else
    MsgBox ("sheet is not empty")
End If
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: delete the `Sheets("sheet1").Copy`-line (keep the second one with the dest part)...

Comment: Haha okay, it was that simple ... thank you very much, it was really annoying :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to have a proper answer:

This behavior is due to the fact that copying a sheet without a destination, a new workbook will be created holding this sheet. For this reason there is no command to "paste" a copied sheet.

For the given code, just remove the line

```
Sheets("sheet1").Copy
```

But keep the line:

```
Sheets("sheet1").Copy After:=StartWorkbook.Sheets("Control")
```

(obviously, it is needed) ;)